# How to add Power Automate Process Advisor generated Power BI pages to another report?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, power-automate, process-mining

I created a process in the Power Automate Process Advisor and through it a Power BI report. This feature requires 2 different licenses: Power Automate Premium and Power BI Premium. Is it technically possible to copy the visuals or pages of this report to another Power BI report? Additionally, is it possible to combine the Power BI reports of 2 different Power Automate processes?

From the generated report I tried to copy the visuals or the pages to an existing report. It seems though that this intentionally blocked by Microsoft, because of the aforementioned required licenses.